# Regex: Expression selecting more than expected

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following regex

```
'/\@(.*)\((.*)\)/'
```

And I am trying to get @ONE(TWO) one and two from the expression. Which works as long as it's the only time that it can be found before an end of line (I think)

I am quite green with regex and I really cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

What I need is to be able to get all the ONE/TWO couples. Can you please help me.

I am working with PHP and the following function

```
$parsed_string = preg_replace_callback(
    // Placeholder for not previously created article
    // Pattern example: @George Ioannidis(person)             
    '/\@(.*)\((.*)\)/', 
    function ($matches) {
        return $this->parsePlaceholders( $matches );
    },
    $string
);
```

**The results I am getting from https://regexr.com**
[image: The results I am getting from https://regexr.com/]

Comment: can you please add the original link to your regex website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` expression is greedy by default. For example such regexp `(.*)a` will return you `bdeabde` result on `bdeabdea` string.  You should use special `?` symbol for non-greedy `*` behavior. In your case try to use `/\@(.*?)\((.*?)\)/` regexp.

Comment: Thank you very much - it worked like a charm. Thank you for explaining "greedy" It makes sense now.